# Loopback 4 - How to find the highest value in column (Like SELECT MAX(column) from Table)?

Tags: sql, loopback, loopback4

I want to find the highest value in a specific column of a specific table. It should be very simple.
this is the documentation of LB4 https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter But I didn't find it there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the [Loopback Filter Documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html#gt-and-lt) they do mention a way to achieve this, even though it's not as obvious.

```
/weapons?filter[where][effectiveRange][gt]=900&filter[limit]=3
```

**Essentially you can do the following:**

1. Identify the column of interest.
2. Use the `gt` operator to set a min number
3. Add `order` if you wanted to ensure the sorting order is as expected.
4. Limit the results to 1.

*Here is a code example:*

```
Employees.find({
  where: {
    age: {
      gt: 1
    }
  },
  order: 'age ASC',
  limit: 1
})
```

Please let me know if this is what you were going for or if you need some more support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw this documentation. But I was hoping for something simpler like the "Max" attribute.

Answer (score 2):

We did this through a custom repository method where we execute a select max() query and have a custom controller method (i.e. /next-id) that calls it.

Repository method:

```
  async nextId(): Promise<any> {
    return this.dataSource
      .execute('select MAX(id)+5 as nextId from route_lookup')
      .then(data => {
        if (data[0].NEXTID === null) {
          data[0].NEXTID = 1005;
        }
        return data[0].NEXTID;
      });
  }
```

Controller method:

```
  @get('/route-lookups/next-id')
  @response(200, {
    description: 'Next avaialble id for route lookup',
    content: {
      'application/json': {
        schema: {
          type: 'number',
        },
      },
    },
  })
  async nextId(): Promise<number> {
    return await this.routeLookupRepository.nextId();
  }
```